# How get the row that causes the error when Appling Updates

Tags: delphi, unidac

I have a TUniquery in CachedUpdates mode when applying updates with ApplyUpdates an exception is raised due to a Database constraint,
is there a way to get the record that causes the error?

Edit : Trying to migrate from FIBPlus where the OnUpdateError of the TpFIBDataset component catch the exact record where the update fails.

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: The project XXXXXXX.exe raised the exception class EIBCError with message 'validation error for column "ARTICLE"."QUANTITY", value "-1.000000000000000"
At trigger 'BL_DETAIL_AI_QUANTITY' line: 13, col: 5'.